# Number of simple cycles on the xy-plane

Tags: combinatorics

We start at the origin, with a number $K=0$. For each step, we move one unit horizontally or vertically. For every vertical step, we add the x-coordinate of that point to $K$ if we go up, and subtract it from $K$ if we go down.

How many simple cycles (i.e., the path ends at the origin, not crossing itself except for the origin) are there ending up with $K=\pm5$?

For example, a rectangular path $(0,0)\to (1,0)\to(1,5)\to(0,5)\to(0,0)$ is such a path.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Not really, since he's adding "x-coordinate" each time. For instance $(0,0)\to(0,1)\to(1,1)\to(0,1)\to(0,0)$ would have $K=1$

Comment: @user160738: Yes, I caught that as soon as I posted the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observation:** We have 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{curl}{curl}
K 
= \int\limits_C (0, x) \cdot (dx, dy)
= \int\limits_C (0, x, 0) \cdot du
= \int\limits_C A \cdot du
= \int\limits_S \curl A \cdot dS
= \int\limits_S (0,0,1) \cdot dS
= \lvert S \rvert
$$
due to extension into third dimension and Stokes theorem, so we get $K$ by determining the area, thus counting the squares within the loop.

**Note:** This is an oriented area, we get its normal (up or down) by the right hand rule. A counter clockwise running loop has positive area, a clockwise running loop has negative area.

**Equivalent problem:**
The number of simple cycles of a given $K$ value is the number of "unit-square areas" of (oriented) area size $K$, containing the origin as border point and the border curve not having intersections, except for the origin.

For $K = 1$ we have $4+2$ such areas.

[image]
[image]

Where we touch the origin, but do not cross for the diagonal blocks.

For $K = 2$ this seem to be $4 \times 2$ + $4$ + $2 = 14$ areas.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here we cross the origin for the diagonal blocks.

Comment: You should have $2\cdot6+2\cdot7=12+14=26$ for $K=2$: each of the two  dominoes (horizontal and vertical) can have the origin at any of its $6$ vertices, and each of the two ‘diagonal dominoes’ can have the origin at any of its $7$ vertices. A similar analysis yields $6\cdot8+8\cdot9=120$ for $K=3$.

Comment: It appears that the brute force approach is to find all of the connected arrangements of $K$ unit squares and count each one once for each lattice point on its boundary.

Comment: The diagonal ones seem to be only two. Because that intersection is only allowed at the origin.

Comment: Is that his *Diskrete Mathematik*? Judging by the two-page sample visible at Springer, he gets right down to business. And you’re right about the diagonal ones; that reduces the $K=3$ count to $48+8=56$.

Comment: Yes. I have the German edition.